# Convergence of sum of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose a vector valued function $f$ is defined by an infinite sum of differentiable mappings $f_k : \Bbb R ^n \to \Bbb R ^m$ absolutely convergent on some domain $E$. Let $f$ be differentiable on $E$. Does it follow that the sum of the derivatives of $f_k$, should it also absolutely converge, converges to $f'$ on $E$? I'm seeking a generalization of the the theorem proved in Rudin's "Principles".

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is negative.**

You can derive a counterexample from Rudin's book that you mention: exercise 7 of chapter 7.

Take for $n \ge 1$ the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+n x^2}$$ One can prove that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ and that the equation $$f^\prime(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f^\prime_n(x)$$ is correct for $x \neq 0$, but false for $x =0$.

Then, you can convert this sequence example to a series one by considering the series of functions $$g_1(x)=f_1(x) \text{ and } g_{n+1}(x) = f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)$$ for $n \ge 1$. You'll verify that the sequence $(g_n)$ has the properties of absolute convergence that you require.